# ASP.NET MVC reporting 404 missing page errors for background CSS images and favourite icons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I have ignored this question for a fair few years, but it still worries me.  I have in my shared layout page lines like this:

[image]

In my SCSS file I have lines like this (these are faithfully reproduced in the same way in the underlying CSS files; I've checked):

[image]

All of these work fine - usually.  But over time our website records hundreds of 404 errors for files like this.  Here are a couple of errors recorded in our internal log table:

[image]

So the problem isn't the webpage /blog/, which works fine, it's the images referenced on it.  How can this work on most pages but not all of them?  I'm baffled!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I may have an answer.  In the CSS style sheet for the website, many of the images are set as backgrounds - for example:

[image]

The path above is absolute, but before it was a relative path:

[image]

Although this worked fine (the path was relative to the location of the browser, not to the location of the web page being viewed), I am guessing that some spiders weren't programmed well enough to appreciate the difference, and took the path of images like this as relative to the page being requested rather than the style sheet.